# Change start index in combobox?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, combobox

I have a form with different text boxes where you can save the info from a person in a table. There is also a combo box showing five values from another table, where you will be able to select and save at the same table as they appear from.

The problem is that the combo box is 0-index based and the table begins at 1. When I save the second entry it really saves the third. If I choose the first item in the combo this error appears: *"FOREIGN KEY conflict"*...

Is it possible to set the start-index to 1 in the combo, or is it the keys in the two tables that are wrong?

I don't find a way to fix this.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("INSERT INTO Employee (Name1, Email, Salary,"+
            "DateofBirth, OnparantalLeave, DepartmentId) " + 
            "VALUES (@Name1, @Email, @Salary, @DateofBirth,"+
            "@OnparantalLeave, @DepartmentId)", MyConnection.GetConnection());
command.Connection = MyConnection.GetConnection();
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name1", textBoxNameF2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBoxMailF2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", textBoxSalF2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofBirth", SqlDbType.Date).Value =
        dateTimePickerF2.Value.Date;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OnparantalLeave", checkBoxParantF2.Checked);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", comboBoxDepF2.SelectedIndex);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Parameters.Clear();
this.Close();
```

Comment: It seems a little strange to me to use `SelectedIndex` as database ID, but anyway, why not simply `comboBoxDepF2.SelectedIndex+1`?

Comment: why dont you bind your ComboBox's `ValueMember` and get it from selected item? why index?

Comment: As René Vogt said, it is very strange to use index as database ID, you must capture the object and pass the ID. Another tip, separate your project into classes. Access to the seat should not be inside the view.

Comment: Working now! command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", comboBoxDepF2.SelectedValue);

Comment: Thank you so mutch!!! :)